# Remove the query string before appending the url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I want to remove the query string from my URL before I add my URL parameters. Say my site is https://www.abcd.com/test I am appending some parameters to my URL like /def?key=value through javascript. But the page is built as https://www.abcd.com/test?/def?key=value. I want it to be https://www.abcd.com/test/def?key=value Below is my code. Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
redirectURL: function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;

    var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    if (kvp == '') {
        if (currentURL.indexOf("def") == -1){ 
            document.location.search = '/def'+ '?' + 'key' + '=' + 'value';
        }else{
            document.location.search = '?' + 'key' + '=' + 'value';
        }
    }
    else {
        var i = kvp.length; var x; while (i--) {
            x = kvp[i].split('=');

            if (x[0] == key) {
                x[1] = value;
                kvp[i] = x.join('=');
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i < 0) { kvp[kvp.length] = [key, value].join('='); }

        document.location.search = kvp.join('&');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending your *URL parameters* to the `location.search` property which is the querystring:

```
document.location.search = '/def'+ '?' + 'key' + '=' + 'value';
```

I believe what you want to do is append your *URL parameters* to the `location.href` property, but first you will need to separate the existing `search` string (querystring) from it:

```
var urlBase = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
window.location.href = urlBase + '/def'+ '?' + 'key' + '=' + 'value';
```